# Reverse-engineering hot tub control signal

Tags: signal-processing, reverse-engineering

I am trying to reverse engineer the control signal that my hot tub's top side control panel uses to communicate with the main panel which controls the heater, water pump, etc. The tub is an older (early/mid 2000s) Vita Spa.

The top side control panel plugs into the main control panel with a 4 wire RJ style jack. I cannot tell what the microprocessors are as there is no writing on them, but it appears that the same 28 pin chip was used in both the control panel and main board.

The top side panel is an [L-50](https://www.vitaparts.com/460098-vita-spa-universal-spa-side-control-l-50-0460098-30460098.aspx) and is potted so I cannot really examine the circuit, however I have observed that if I unplug the control panel from the main panel, the pump and heater shut off - which indicates to me that the top side panel is what is actually doing the temperature monitoring and control.

If this assumption is true, then the temperature must be sent from the main panel to the top side panel, and the top side panel is telling the main panel when to turn on the heat, water pump, jets, etc.

**Photos & Connection**

There are four wires, 16v power, ground and two signal/communication wires.

[image: main control board]
[image: top side panel]

**Data Logging**

I logged the signal with Sigrok pulseview and found that there is a constant signal being sent/received, regardless of whether the tub is running or idle. [Available on GitHub Here](https://github.com/PaulWieland/HotTubControl).

**Not a UART?**

I tried decoding as a UART, but it doesn't seem to be a serial signal as there are many frame errors no matter what baud rate I use. It also doesn't seem like the framing of D1 and D0 align.

**So what protocol is this?**

Can I rule out serial?

What else uses 4 wires?

[image: pulseview]

[image: pulseview zoomed out]

---

**EDIT 1:**

Per @kartman's suggestion I tried the I2C decoder. I'm not sure if its decoding correctly either as it doesn't give any frame errors the way the uart decoder does. I do see a NACK. If I reverse the clock and data channels it still doesn't output errors, so it's hard to say if the decoder is outputting the actual data or just noise.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like serial to me - lower trace is clock, upper trace is data. Might be I2C but is probably not uart.

Comment: Look like a proprietary bit-bang protocol  repeating 2 bytes each with parity using negative pulse on data to trigger frame start then next negative edge on clock is 1st active.  Made so it's hard to see frame sync, word sync and byte sync with parity and redundancy

Comment: @Kartman I just tried the I2C decoder. See edit in original post, I added screenshots for i2c. just not sure if the data is valid

Comment: the microcontroller seems to have the same pinout as the microchip PIC18 series.

Comment: 4 wires could be SPI.  The other two wires would be a second data line and a select, which should go high for the duration of each packet (even with one client it needs to sync sometimes).

Comment: I wonder if it is RS422 2 wire communicaiton, and the other 2 are +/- power? I have a older (2005?) Connect-tech MiniMax control and Orca Bay topside with 4 wire. I'd like to try interface a Arduino or something to have a remote monitor/control system being able to see and adjust temperature. This page mentions a R59D processor chip. https://www.a1spacontrol.com/correct-tech-cti-topside-control-panel-mini-max-1-630rs and this page sells a ATMEGA8-16 processor chip for it. https://thehottubsuperstore.com/product/cti-processor-chip-mmd-atmega8-16pc/

Comment: You know the manufacturer of the top panel - it's right on the label :) Their website at the very least still exists - asking them may yield results (or not), but it's at least worth trying. https://www.consumerengineering.com/

Comment: The solution was to just ditch the entire control system and write my own ESP based one that controls the relays on the original logic board. Has been working flawlessly for over a year and a half with the added bonus of being able to control the temp from my home automation system (automatic temp down due to weather or when away for extended periods).